# how to get number of children in html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to understand the behavior of `jquery` method `children`. I am able to count the number of `<p>` in a `<div>` using :

```
   var abc = $("div").children("p");
   alert(abc.length);
```

But the same thing when applied to `<tr>` within `<table>` results in 0 (zero) count.

```
   var abc = $("table").children("tr");
   alert(abc.length);
```

why is it so?

Comment: You forgot `<tbody>`. Use `$('table > tbody').children('tr').length;`

Comment: Where's your HTML?

Comment: thanks @Tushar , your solution worked. But I want to know why is it so. I have not included tbody in my table element. then why should I use this for getting children?

Comment: $("table tbody tr").length;

Comment: [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/938083)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$("table tr").length;
```

If you only want to get `tr` within `tbody`

```
$("table tbody tr").length;
```

Comment: OP want direct children only. Either use `children()` or `>` selector.

Answer (score 1):

[`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) will return direct children (traverses single level) of `<table>` but not the grand-child(ie, `children`'s `children`).

If you wish to search in descendants of an element, use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Here is how then you can get the `<tr>` of `<table>`:

```
var trs = $('table').find('tr');
```

And, to get the count/length

```
alert($('table').find('tr').length);
```

**No nested table**
If there is no nested tables, then

```
alert($('table').find('tr').length);
```

or

```
alert($('table tr').length);
```

will give you a proper result.

**Nested tables**
If you are having some nested tables i.e `<table>` inside a `<table>`,

Above code won't give you correct result, if you need `<tr>`s of parent `<table>`, but not of children `<table>`.

Here is how then you can get it:

```
alert($('table>tbody>tr').length);
```

or

```
alert($('table').children('tbody').children('tr').length);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer.

```
alert($("table tr").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use selector that will select all the rows and take length.

```
var tableRowCount = $('table tr').length;
```

This approach also used for get counts all trs of every nested table

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var childrensCount = $('table tr').length;
```

OR

```
var childrensCount = $('#tableId tr').length;
```